# Why does a verb method with parameters block another of the same route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm practicing node.js and express.js by writing some random stuff. So after I wrote a get method with parameters, it blocked another get method from running. I would like to know why.

I am sure that it's because of the 1st method. I deleted it and moved it after the second, and it worked just fine. But when it's before the 2nd, it blocked it.

```
// the following code is the one that blocks
app.get("/animes/:id", (req, res)=>{
res.send(animes[req.params.id]);
});

app.get("/animes/add", (req, res)=>{
console.log(req.query);
res.send("yes")
}); 

// the following code works fine
app.get("/animes/add", (req, res)=>{
console.log(req.query);
res.send("yes")
});

app.get("/animes/:id", (req, res)=>{
res.send(animes[req.params.id]);
});
```

I have two other get methods with routes such as "/" and "animes". I am sure that they are not the reason why it blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middlewares are evaluated in the order they are registered.

So for:

```
app.get("/animes/:id", ... )
app.get("/animes/add", ... )
```

Express will first test if the requested url matches `/animes/:id` and `/animes/:id` will match `/animes/add`, the middleware with registered with `app.get("/animes/add", ... )` would never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example the first route "/animes/:id" matches if you call "animes/add". "add" would be the id-parameter in that case. the secound route would be ignored.